# Search through all collection array in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a nested array of values that look like this in RoboMongo;

[image]

Or this might be slightly clearer;

[image]

Is there a way of being able to (in one query) search through all the key/value pairs with a regex? The script will not know how many customField key/value pairs there are!

So far I have in PHP;

`['poco.customFields.0.value' => ['$regex' => '.*'.$query.'.*', '$options' => 'i']],`

Which is working on the first key/value pair nicely.. But not the others and I don't know how to do that without either doing two queries or just guessing that there will be no more than, say, 100 and just looping through it.

Comment: I am sure this can be done with $where, but not sure the php syntax, you can check $where in which you can pass a javascript function which can loop through the key-value pairs in array.

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you please add it in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to acquire documents with contents of customFields matching specific regex expression, there are two interpretations I can think of.

(1) Return all documents with **at least one** value in customFields matching the pattern:

```
[ 'customFields.value' => [ '$regex' => $pattern, '$options' => 'i' ]]
```

(2) Return all document with **all** values in customFields matching the pattern:

```
[ 'customFields.value' => [ '$not' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('\b^(?!'.$pattern.').+', 'i') ]]
```

The first query is self-explanatory: iterate through all elements of customFields array and perform a regex check on each. If at least one of the elements matches the pattern, the parent document is returned.

The second one is a bit more sophisticated. Requirement "where **all** elements **match** particular pattern" is equivalent to "where **no single** element **does not match** particular pattern". In order to achieve double negation, we use `$not` along with inverse regex expression created by applying negative lookahead to the same query we have used before. Since `$not` refuses to accept strings, we generate immediate regex expression by using an instance of [MongoDB\BSON\Regex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-regex.php) class.

More information on negative lookahead may be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: that's amazing. I've done some tests and it seems to work. I would not have thought that the query would know to iterate through the array instead of just erroring.

Comment: @mikelovelyuk I am very glad I was able to help. Please, consider marking answer as accepted if it did solve your issue completely or add additional details you would like to clarify on if there are any.